# Google ReCapcha causes error on membership contribution page

Tags: civicontribute, joomla

Joomla:  3.4.4
CiviCRM: 4.6.8
PHP:     5.4.43

I have a membership application setup that used to work fine with the v1, Google ReCapcha.  However, the new version, while it displays fine, causes an error when the user clicks continue to head to PayPal.

Scenario:

User fill out membership form.  At the bottom is the new ReCapcha box. 
User clicks the box, gets the checkmark.
User then clicks 'Confirm Contribution' button.
Confirmation screen is displayed for user verification of data.
User then clicks 'Continue' to head to PayPal.

### Screen redisplays with error at top of page:

Error

## The CAPTCHA solution was incorrect

Interesting part - user's data is entered into CiviCRM database, Contribution is listed as 'Pending (Incomplete Transaction)', but no Joomla user record is created.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Form works fine without capcha ..

8

Comment: Update:   the Member Application profile data (separate from the Member Profile) data did NOT make it to the database.